# Mock ViewChild Element in Angular Test (of components in packages)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing

In my component's class, I have `ViewChild` variables, like so:

```
@ViewChild("chipList") chipList;
@ViewChild("autocompleteChipInput") autocompleteChipInput: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
@ViewChild("autocompleteTrigger") autocompleteTrigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
```

Here is (some of) the component template:

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-chip-list #chipList>
      <mat-chip>...</mat-chip>
      <input matInput #autocompleteChipInput #autocompleteTrigger="matAutocompleteTrigger" .../>
   </mat-chip-list>
   <mat-autocomplete #autocompleteChips="matAutocomplete">...</mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

I'm now writing unit tests, and in my class logic I'm using the `chipList`, `autocompleteChipInput`, and `autocompleteTrigger` variables. In my current tests, they're showing as undefined, so I can't trigger certain logic.
How can I mock out these elements in my tests?
I've seen lots of examples on how to mock a childComponent, but those components are coming from external packages and I can't figure out how to apply it to them.

Comment: On this subject, I have found this article to be well written: https://indepth.dev/posts/1184/angular-unit-testing-viewchild. Although, I think if you add `MatFormFieldModule` and the other required modules in the `imports` array of `TestBed.configureTestingModule`, I don't think they will be undefined anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a mocking library. For example, such as [`ng-mocks`](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/guides/view-child).

An example with Angular Material: https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/guides/libraries/angular-material

It will replace all dependencies with mocks, so `@ViewChild` is still to find related instances and build the properties of your component correctly:

```js
// ItsModule should import / declare all dependencies of YourComponent.
beforeEach(() => MockBuilder(YourComponent, ItsModule));

// This call let you customize mock instances in tests.
MockInstance.scope();

it('should do something', () => {
  // creating a spy
  const spy = MockInstance(MatChipList, 'autocompleteTrigger', jasmine.createSpy());

  const fixture = MockRender(YourComponent);

  // an example, not sure if the spy has been triggered somehow.
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```